# MVC Localizations with multi resources files

Tags: razor, localization, resources, asp.net-mvc-5

I am localizing a MVC 5 page. There are lots of strings and pages in the site. 
Is it possible to use multi resources for one given language ?

What I mean is how can I use resourcesMainpage.en.resx  , resourcesSecondpage.en.resx .. etc for english language ? ( where all languages will have 3-4 different resources files)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. The only benefit I see from this approach is better organization of your resources.